# Webpack - Can't resolve jquery

Tags: webpack-2

I'm new to webpack and I'm actually stucked. I read some articles about webpack and so started trying it on a project (just on third part libraries). I have created my entry-point.js:

```
require('angular');
require('angular-bootstrap');
require('angular-file-upload');
require('angular-local-storage');
require('angular-ui-grid');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('ng-idle');
require('bootstrap');
require('jquery');
```

and the webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
entry : './entry-point.js',
output : {
    path : __dirname + "/dist",
    filename : 'vendor.js'
},
resolve : {
    modules : [ 'bower_components' ]
}
```

};

but when I launch the 'npm start' I get the following error:

> **Module not found: Error:** Can't resolve 'jquery' in
>   'D:\Documents\Sviluppo\Eclipse\Workspace\SCARICO-TeamcenterEasyApp\target\TeamcenterEasyApp-0.0.1'
>   resolve 'jquery' in
>   'D:\Documents\Sviluppo\Eclipse\Workspace\SCARICO-TeamcenterEasyApp\target\TeamcenterEasyApp-0.0.1'

Obviously the library is present in my bower_components folder. 
Note: webpack version 2.2.1

And this is my package.json:

```
{
 "name": "TeamcenterEasyApp-0.0.1",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "entry-point.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "webpack"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact path to jQuery's JS file?

Comment: Y, it's bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js. But does it just search in the jquery folder? or also in the subfolders?

Comment: What is `bower_components/jquery/package.json`?

Comment: There isn't a bower_components/jquery/package.json. Just a bower.json.

Comment: That's your problem; Webpack has no way of knowing to look for `dist/jquery.js` in that package.

Comment: Ok, that was helpful.... and fast. Thank you!